# Is there a way to allow downgrades with apt Ansible module?

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible Playbook to deploy a specific version of docker. I want apt module to allow for downgrades when the target machine have a higher version installed. I browsed the documentation but couldn't find a suitable way to do it. The Yaml file have lines like:

```
- name : "Install specific docker ce"
  become : true 
  apt : 
    name : docker-ce=5:18.09.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic
    state : present
```

Comment: Is that playbook snippet producing an _error_ or is it just not downgrading your `docker-ce` package?

Comment: I'm having an error, task failed to complete. The error is :    "stderr": "E: Packages were downgraded and -y was used without --allow-downgrades.\n",

Comment: According to [the fine manual](https://manpages.debian.org/wheezy/dpkg/dpkg.1.en.html#OPTIONS), `--force-downgrade` is legal, and thus [`apt: dpkg_options: ["force-downgrade"]`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/apt_module.html#parameters) should allow it to downgrade; can you try that?

Comment: I'm still getting an error  :( .  "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--['force-downgrade']\"     install 'docker-ce=5:18.09.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic'' failed: E: Packages were downgraded and -y was used without --allow-downgrades.\n",
    "stderr": "E: Packages were downgraded and -y was used without --allow-downgrades.\n",

Comment: try it with `force: yes` option.

Comment: Damn, that's my fault: as you can see from the presence of `--['force-downgrade']` they don't want a list of string they just split on `","` so it should have been `dpkg_options: force-downgrade`; I'm sorry for not catching that

Answer (score 1):

For Docker CE on Ubuntu there are two packages, `docker-ce` and `docker-ce-cli`. You can see which versions are currently installed with:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep docker
docker-ce/xenial,now 5:18.09.7~3-0~ubuntu-xenial amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5:19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-xenial]
docker-ce-cli/xenial,now 5:18.09.7~3-0~ubuntu-xenial amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5:19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-xenial]
```

You need to force the same version for both packages. e.g. on Ubuntu Xenial:

#### main.yml

```yaml
- name: Install docker-ce
  apt:
    state: present
    force: True
    name:
    - "docker-ce=5:18.09.7~3-0~ubuntu-xenial"
    - "docker-ce-cli=5:18.09.7~3-0~ubuntu-xenial"
  notify:
    - Restart docker
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian" and ansible_distribution_version == "16.04"
```

#### handler.yml

```yaml
# Equivalent to `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart docker`
- name: Restart docker
  systemd:
    name: docker
    daemon_reload: True
    state: restarted
```

Answer (score 0):

*allow-downgrade* parameter can be used with apt module. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-allow_downgrade). However note that using this option could end up with a set of packages that does not match the complete list of specified packages to install.